# MetroUI: Cannot change data-autocomplete attribute in autocomplete input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, metro-ui-css

I want to create a dynamic autocomplete input that can be updated using [metroui](https://metroui.org.ua/) and its jquery-like [m4q](https://metroui.org.ua/m4q-about.html) . Based [on its documentation](https://metroui.org.ua/input.html#_input_autocomplete), I need to set the `data-autocomplete` attribute in the `input` tag, but the updated data is not shown after I set it dynamically.

Here's my autocomplete `input`:

```
<input id="search-term"
         class="w-100 w-50-md"
         type="text"
         data-role="input"
         name="search-term"
         placeholder="Cari istilah..."
         data-autocomplete="">
```

Here's the script at the bottom of the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // load demo data
  const terms = Object(<?php echo json_encode(array_keys(load_demo_data())) ?>);
  let termsToString = terms.toString();
  termsToString = termsToString.replace(/,/g, ', ');
  // console.log(termsToString);
  $('#search-term').attr('data-autocomplete', termsToString);
</script>
```

Here's `terms` variable:

[image]

But see that there's no auto-completion:

[image]

So how do I get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by using `m4q`'s `insertAfter` method. So I just made an anchor tag with an id, and insert my autocomplete `input` tag using `m4q` / `jQuery`, after that anchor:

```html
    <form class="d-flex flex-wrap" action="definition.php" method="post">
      <a id="search-term-index"></a>

      <button type="submit"
              class="w-100 w-25-md mt-2 mt-0-md ml-2-md button primary">
        Cari
      </button>
    </form>
```

```js
    $("<input class=\"w-100 w-50-md\" type=\"text\" data-role=\"input\" name=\"search-term\" placeholder=\"Cari istilah...\" data-autocomplete=\"" + termsToString + "\">")
      .insertAfter('#search-term-index');
```